# between clause for varchar type in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have a field campaign_code in sql which has values in chronological order with 'C' as initial alphabet *(eg. C143,C144, C145,etc)*.

I want to fetch data of multiple campain_code. eg. all the data from C144 to C146. The problem is that sql doesnt take value of type varchar for `between` clause. Please help me.

Comment: *The problem is that sql doesnt take value of type varchar for "between" clause* - This is not true

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the method you describe as not working does work and is the way to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `campaign_code` to number and then use `between` :

```
select *
from table
where cast(replace(campaign_code, 'C','') as int) between 140 and 150
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d5ff/6)

Answer (score 2):

does the following not work (between does indeed work on string values):??

```
SELECT * FROM campaign
WHERE campaign_code BETWEEN 'C144' and 'C146';
```

it should treat the ansi ordering as if comparing numbers and give you the result. there are a few google refs on the topic, perhaps a play at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between_text may help to show the possibilities and limitations

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question and a special thanks to grisha. you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where substring(compain_code, 2, 10) between 144 and 146
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "doesn't take value of type varchar for "between" clause", because MS says it does [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx).

You just have to make sure that all the expressions (test_, begin_ and end_) are of the same type, so I'm guessing your test_expression is not of type varchar?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
  select * from tablename where id >(select id from tablename where campain_code='C144') and id<(select id from tablename where campain_code='C146')
```